# Stop clock when page is not on screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, setinterval

in the title I used a clock as an example but my question is for all functions.
How do I stop some function when it is not on-screen. For the clock I used the `useEffect` Hook with `setInterval()`, since I am using ReactJs. So how do I stop the interval when the page is not visible on the screen so it does not slow down the users computer. I read that it is not possible to stop setInterval so I know that I need to `clearInterval` and and `setInterval` again.

Comment: Simply return a cleanup function in ```useEffect``` which clears the interval using ```clearInterval```, so that whenever the component unmounts, the functionality in ```useEffect``` stop working.

Comment: @YashSharma , I know but this, but when I switch the tab or got to another screen, doesn't unmount the component. It is still mounted.

Comment: By another screen, you mean another page?

Comment: does not matter. When the cursor is not on the page of the clock.